# Need to change the text in a lot of files at once

Tags: files, webserver, editing

I have migrated over web and DB files from one server to another and need to change the text in a lot of PHP files from the IP of the old server to 'localhost' where the databases can now be found.

What is the easiest way of making the change in all the files at the same time?  The alternative is manually editing 8 A4 pages of file names. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use `sed`, for example:

`sed -i 's/192.168.0.1/localhost/g' *.php` will take all of the PHP files in your current folder, and replace (globally) the IP address "192.168.0.1" with "localhost".

Edit: This might not be helpful, come to think of it - I'm not overly familiar with PHP, so am not sure if the data within is stored in plaintext. If it is, then this will help; if not, then I don't know for sure how to go about it.

Comment: It is all plain text.  I will copy a few files to my home Linux server and try there this command before committing to the real one.  Thank you.

Comment: Is there an option to make this command recursive through all the directories?

Comment: For that you want to use xargs:

`find ./* -name '*.php' | xargs sed -i 's/192.168.0.1/localhost/g'`

This will find all php files recursively from the current directory and run sed on them.